# OpenGL - glVertexAttribPointer with multiple VBOs and VAOs using the same shader

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-attributes

I have multiple VBOs and matching VAOs set up in my rendering engine. I am a bit confused about using glVertexAttribPointer. I have set it and it renders fine but I am curious if I am using one shader (a basic diffuse) with all of these different objects, do I set glVertexAttribPointer each time I create a VAO. I guess what's throwing me is I am trying to figure out if my setting an attribute pointer, is that set in the shader or the vertex array object. I assume it's the vertex array object but am hoping for some clarification.

Comment: [Read this.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) That should make the relations between buffer objects and VAOs clear.

Answer (score 2):

Vertex attribute pointers are per vertex array object (VAO).  The [OpenGL 4.3 specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec43.core.20130214.pdf) on page 318 in the description of `glGetVertexAttribPointerv` specifies: *The value returned is queried from the currently bound vertex array object.*